# Executing a command (from variable) and then showing the correct pid?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a bash script in which I would like to do something like this:

```
_command="zcat database.sql.gz | mysql database"

eval "($_command) & echo $!"
```

I want to run a command in the background (stored in a variable) from a bash script and then return the correct `pid` for that application.

As of above, it currently returns the `pid` of the bash script instead...

Does someone know how to make this work?

EDIT:

If I put it like this; how would you do if you wanted to do this?

what I really wanna do is just write this:

($_command) & echo $! - But then I get an error stating gzip doesn't understand the command "-u", somehow gzip thinks the mysql commands belongs to it. Strange.

Comment: Which pid? The one for `zcat` or the one for `mysql`?

Comment: the one from the background process running these two commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
eval "($_command) & echo $!"
```

`$!` is being expanded *before* `eval` is run.  Try escaping it, e.g. `"\$!"` or `'$!'`.

Comment: Now it just returns the bash scripts pid number - when what I really need is the background process pid.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
eval "($_command) & echo $$"
```

Comment: This gave me a pid number of something that had finished executing when I looked it up... :/

Comment: $ sleep 100 &
[1] 192

$ echo $!
192

Comment: jobs -l will give you all backgroup running process

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with that actually worked:

```
    _command="zcat dump.sql.gz | mysql database"

    function run {

            $1="($1)"

            `eval $_command` & echo $!
    }   

    run $_command
```

Thanks for all the nice people taking their time to try and help me out! :)